# How to filter rows based on window and a condition in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window

I need to remove rows where for the same id, p_id and key_id, feedback is missing but we do have some of the feedback present.

input

```
id p_id key_id feedback
1  p1   k1     happy
1  p1   k1     sad
1  p1   k2     sad
1  p1   k2     
1  p2   k3  
2  p1   k3     sad
```

output

```
   id p_id key_id feedback
    1  p1   k1     happy
    1  p1   k1     sad
    1  p1   k2     sad
    1  p2   k3  
    2  p1   k3     sad
```

How can I achieve that in pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a new column called `min_length` and filter by that column and the `feedback` column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.window.Window as W

df = df.withColumn('min_length', 
                   F.min(F.length(F.trim(F.col('feedback'))))
                    .over(W.partitionBy('id', 'p_id', 'key_id'))
                  )

cond = (F.col('min_length') != 0) & (F.length(F.trim(F.col('feedback'))) == 0)

df.filter(~cond)
```

The trims are just stripping off any spaces in the `feedback` column

Comment: Thank you, i did a little tweak to make it 0 if the value is None using coalesce else it was skipping that check while doing length

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column (let's call it *num_feedbacks*) for each key ([*id*, *p_id*, *key_id*]) that counts how many feedback for that key you have in the DataFrame.
Then you can filter your DataFrame keeping only the rows where you have a feedback (*feedback* is not Null) or you do not have any feedback for that specific key.

Here is the code example:

```
key = ['id', 'p_id', 'key_id']

num_feedbacks = df.filter(col('feedback')!="")\
.groupby(key).agg(F.count('feedback').alias('num_feedbacks'))

df = df.join(num_feedbacks, on=key, how='left')\
.filter((col('feedback')!="") | (col('num_feedbacks').isNull()))\
.drop('num_feedbacks')
```

Which gives you:

```
+---+----+------+--------+
| id|p_id|key_id|feedback|
+---+----+------+--------+
|  2|  p1|    k3|     sad|
|  1|  p1|    k1|     sad|
|  1|  p1|    k1|   happy|
|  1|  p1|    k2|     sad|
|  1|  p2|    k3|        |
+---+----+------+--------+
```